# Amount of $1$s or $0$s in binary expansion of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binary

*Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601370/find-the-number-of-1s-or-0s-in-binary-representation-of-a-number).*

---

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{Z^+}\to\mathbb{Z^+}$, where $\mathbb{Z^+}$ denotes the positive integers, defined by:

$$
f(n)=3^n+3n,
$$

and the function $g$, also $\mathbb{Z^+}\to\mathbb{Z^+}$, that counts the amount of $1$s in the binary expansion of a given positive integer.

Then what is:

$$
g(f(n))?
$$

In general, if one defines the function:

$$
f_{k}(n)=k^n+kn,
$$

how may one find:

$$
g(f_k(n))?
$$

---

EDIT: I understand this is a hard problem. Consider then instead the function $g'$ defined as follows:

$$
g'(n) = 
\begin{cases}
  1 & \rm {if }\ \ g(n)\equiv0\mod2, \\
  0 & \rm {otherwise },
\end{cases}
$$

i.e., $g'$ is equal to $1$ if the amount of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$ is *even*, and $0$ otherwise. Is finding $g'$ easier than finding $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a simple exact formula.  You can get an approximation by noting that $3^n$ has $\lceil \log_2 3^n \rceil$ bits and guessing that half will be $1$s.  This gives $n\frac {\log_2 3}2$ one bits.  The $+3n$ will affect only the bottom few bits, so is not important when $n$ is large.  The extension to $k$ is $n \frac {\log_2 k}2$

Comment: Thank you. I edited my answer to include an "easier" case.

Comment: No, I don't think it is any easier.  Problems with digit expansion are hard unless there is a simple divisibility test that solves them.